# Does Azure start up another instance of a scheduled web job if it is already running?

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I have a Azure web job that is scheduled to run every 5 minutes using the cron expression in the settings.job file. If the process doesn't finish within 5 minutes will Azure kick off another instance of the job or will it wait until the first one finishes?

I would like to make sure it waits until the first one finishes so it isn't running multiple instances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a scheduled webjob is started, Azure places a lock file. This lock file will remain until the scheduled webjob is completed. If there's an attempt to fire up another scheduled job, you'll get a ConflictException.

You can read about the lock file [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#user-content-scheduling-a-triggered-webjob). And the code that checks to see if another job is already running is [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/366955ed56935212b1b65796d33d8b0e178d123e/Kudu.Core/Jobs/TriggeredJobRunner.cs#L55).